# Finding the column number of the only zero within a row in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a large matrix consisting of only ones and zeros. Among the rows that contain only one zero, I need to find the index of that zero (or column number of the zero).

I am trying to use the following command but it returns me only the row number of the concerned row. Can anyone tell me how to modify this command or add an extra command to find the column number of that zero as well?

```
find(sum(~A,2) == 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `min` to find indices of the minimum element of each row then use row numbers to extract indices of columns:

```
[~, idx] = min(A, [], 2);
r = find(sum(~A, 2) == 1);
c = idx(r);
```

It may be more efficient if you use:

```
r = find(sum(A, 2) == size(A,2)-1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that `sum(~A,2) == 1` is a column vector, so you loose data about which column you want.

You can do the following:

```
% (A == 0)         : Elements where A is zero
% (sum(~A,2) == 1) : Rows where there's exactly 1 zero
% We want the matrix where both of these are true...
idx = (sum(~A,2) == 1) .* (A == 0);  
% We want the row and column indices of the zeros
[r,c] = find( idx );
```

Example:

```
% A with single-zero rows in positions (2,1) and (4,2)
A = [ 1 1 1 1 1 1
      0 1 1 1 1 1
      1 0 1 0 1 1 
      1 0 1 1 1 1 
      1 1 1 1 1 1 
      1 1 1 1 0 0 ];

idx = (sum(~A,2) == 1) .* (A == 0); % Could replace (A==0) with (~A)
[r,c] = find(idx)

% r = [2; 4]
% c = [1; 2];
```

---

Note: this depends on implicit expansion, compatible with MALTAB R2016b or newer. You didn't mention your version in the question, but for older versions use this for `idx`:

```
idx = bsxfun( @times, (sum(~A,2) == 1), (A == 0) );
```

Comment: Why `times`, and not `and`?

Comment: @Cris I didn't have MATLAB to hand, and wasn't sure if `&` used implicit expansion, knew it would work with multiplication. Can't imagine there's much of a performance impact either way?

Comment: No, I don’t think it matters at all. I just find `&` more logical when combining logical matrices. The one outputs doubles, the other a logical matrix, so if size matters... :)

Comment: I've deleted my answer that was similar to yours but I agree with @CrisLuengo that `&` seems more natural. `[r,c] = find(~A &  sum(~A,2) == 1)`. You can eventually add this option to your answer.

Comment: By the way: [The supported operator and function](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/#7ae98937-5ed3-4709-a817-61c8682a2ffb) for implicit expansion

Comment: @obchardon: Nice list! They did say they’d add support for other functions over time, do you think they kept that list up to date?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I don't think that the blog posts are updated ! Ho and Wolfie have you noticed that you can use the Matlab live editor if you don't have matlab installed on your computer !

Answer (score 1):

You can run your command once again, in next direction. If you have undefined number of rows, it would be handy to do it in loop:

```
rows = find(sum(~A,2) == 1);
columns=[];
for i = 1:length(rows)
    columns(end+1)=find(sum(~A(rows(i),:),1)==1);
end
disp(rows)
disp(columns)
```